# ComboBox with sections populated from database c#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, combobox

As the title suggests i am trying to create a ComboBox with a different header for each type of data contained within. The data comes from an sql database i have created.

Below is an example of what i need. Headers followed by their appropriate data. In this case two database columns are needed on each line.(I am working with biological data in my example)

**Neuropeptide**

C39E6.6  Npr-1

T05A1.1  Npr-2

**Somatostatin**

F56B6.5  Npr-16

C06G4.5  Npr-17

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Laptop-R5RMQMM8;Initial Catalog=NematodeGPCR - Version 2;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.KnownGenes Where KnownGenes.GeneID IS NOT NULL", sqlConnection);

    sqlConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (sqlReader.Read())
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(sqlReader["Geneid"].ToString());
        comboBox1.Items.Add(sqlReader["GeneName"].ToString());
    }

    sqlReader.Close();
}
```

This code fills my ComboBox with the correct database columns but they are not present on one line and do not have the headers i require.

Comment: Assuming WinForms, you would have to look into drawing that yourself.  See the DrawMode property and the DrawItem and MeasureItem events.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about headers but items in `combobox` should be added like

```
while (sqlReader.Read())
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(new Item(sqlReader["GeneName"].ToString(), sqlReader["Geneid"].ToString()));
}
```

Or (to show text and id in combobox)

```
while (sqlReader.Read())
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(new Item(sqlReader["GeneName"].ToString()  + ‘ ‘  + sqlReader["Geneid"].ToString(), sqlReader["Geneid"].ToString()));
}
```